# Setting up pure css arrows to menu with transparent or image background?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I am trying to apply a pure css arrow to my SELECTED link of horizontal and vertical menu but can't seem to figure out the outcome I wanted. Some similar solutions here at stackoverflow but it doesn't solve my issue.

UL has a border and that's where the problem is coming from... But I shouldn't remove the UL border.

[FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/wvs9o8oy/1/)

```
<li class="selected"><a href="#">Arrow please</a></li>
```

[image: Objective]

```css
ul.hor {
  border-bottom: 3px solid blue;
}
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}
ul li.selected a {
  color: green;
}
ul li.selected:after {
  content: "";
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  border-top: 3px solid blue;
  border-right: 3px solid blue;
}
ul.hor li.selected:after {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: -8px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  -moz-transform: rotate(315deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(315deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(315deg);
}
ul.ver li.selected:after {
  right: -8px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -6px;
  -moz-transform: rotate(225deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(225deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(225deg);
}
ul.ver {
  width: 200px;
  border-right: 3px solid blue;
}
ul.ver li {
  display: block;
}
ul.ver li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}
body {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 20px auto;
  background: rgb(229, 180, 230);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(30deg, rgb(229, 180, 230) 30%, rgb(90, 140, 250) 70%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(30deg, rgb(229, 180, 230) 30%, rgb(90, 140, 250) 70%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(30deg, rgb(229, 180, 230) 30%, rgb(90, 140, 250) 70%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(30deg, rgb(229, 180, 230) 30%, rgb(90, 140, 250) 70%);
  background: linear-gradient(120deg, rgb(229, 180, 230) 30%, rgb(90, 140, 250) 70%);
}
```

```html
<ul class="hor">
  <li><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Ipsum</a></li>
  <li class="selected"><a href="#">Sit amet</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Consectetur</a></li>
</ul>
<br>
<ul class="ver">
  <li><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Ipsum</a></li>
  <li class="selected"><a href="#">Sit amet</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Consectetur</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Try to show more of your CSS so that the question may stand better alone even without the fiddle. Also, what is the picture - your intended outcome? There's no context.

Comment: I updated the fiddle and add the arrow. I add a white background to the arrow to highlight the problem. thanks

Comment: If I remove the white background of the arrow, it won't achieve the outcome as shown in the image...

Comment: I hope you get the solution, but I still think showing the CSS that you think caused the problem here will help a lot. If nothing else, you can confirm that you have selected the correct rule that is causing the problem.

Comment: The problem can be clearly seen I think. And I can't understand why you found the image without context... I use fiddle so that users who want to help can easily play with it. I won't stop to find a solution of course and would love to answer my own question if I found one.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but I already stated the problem which is the border of the UL. Posting blocks of codes here will be meaningless in some cases, and it includes this one, so better if I create a fiddle. I already tried those solution you suggested even before posting the question. I just realize that there might be no easy solution for this problem...

Comment: I didn't suggest any solution, I was pointing out what I had to do before I discovered the problem. But yes, I don't think there is an easy solution, that's why I starred it to see if anyone would have an idea :)

Comment: Check out this and apply it accordingly. http://cssarrowplease.com/

Comment: Thanks @web. I'm familiar with that site and also implemented that method, but still it doesn't help :)

Comment: Something like [this?](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/tzgwL8by/). Or chipChocolate.py's pen from a while back now looks good as well [see here](http://codepen.io/chipChocolate/pen/KwgjXd)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This one is easier to position and has a perfect triangle. We are still using transform rotate but no need for transform skew. No need to calculate width as well.
[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/y7bvygn1/1/).

```css
ul {
    overflow: hidden;
}
li {    
    display:inline-block;position: relative;
}
ul li a {
  display: block;padding:20px 15px;
}
ul li.selected a {
  color: green;
}
ul.hor li.selected:before,
ul.hor li.selected:after {
   content: "";
   bottom: 0;
   position: absolute;
   border-bottom:3px solid blue;
   width:9999px;
   margin:0 10px;left:50%;
}
ul.hor li.selected:after {
    left:auto;right:50%;
}
/*vertical menu starts*/
ul.ver {
  width: 200px;
}
ul.ver li {
  display: block;
}
ul.ver li a {
  padding:10px 15px;
}
ul.ver li.selected:before,
ul.ver li.selected:after {
   content: "";
   position: absolute;
   top:50%;
   right: 0;
   border-right:3px solid blue;
   height:9999px;
   margin:10px 0
}
ul.ver li.selected:after {
    top:auto;bottom:50%;
}

/*arrow starts*/
ul li.selected a:after {
    content: "";
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    border: solid blue;
    border-width: 3px 3px 0 0;  
}

ul.hor li.selected a:after {
    top:100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: -10px auto 0; 
    -moz-transform: rotate(315deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(315deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(315deg);
}
ul.ver li.selected a:after {
    left:100%;
    margin-left:-10px;
    -moz-transform:rotate(225deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(225deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(225deg);
}
body {
    width:90%;margin:20px auto;
    background: rgb(229, 180, 230);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(30deg, rgb(229, 180, 230) 30%, rgb(90, 140, 250) 70%);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(30deg, rgb(229, 180, 230) 30%, rgb(90, 140, 250) 70%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(30deg, rgb(229, 180, 230) 30%, rgb(90, 140, 250) 70%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(30deg, rgb(229, 180, 230) 30%, rgb(90, 140, 250) 70%);
background: linear-gradient(120deg, rgb(229, 180, 230) 30%, rgb(90, 140, 250) 70%);
}
```

```html
<ul class="hor">
     <li><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
     <li class="selected"><a href="#">Ipsum</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Sit amet</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Consectetur</a></li>
 </ul>
<br>
 <ul class="ver">
     <li class="selected"><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Ipsum</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Sit amet</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Consectetur</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: Awesome! I never thought this could be possible :) This one is perfect so far.

Answer (score 4):

One approach would be to use absolute positioning with pseudo elements on the selected element.

The arrow is made with borders and `skewX() skewY()` on the pesudo elements. Their with for the horizontal menu and the height for the vertical one are set to a high value and the overflow is hidden on the `<ul>` element  :

```css
ul {
  overflow: hidden;
}
ul li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}
ul li.selected a {
  color: green;
}
.hor .selected:before, .hor .selected:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 7px;
  width: 9999px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0px 4px 3px;
  border-color: blue;
}
.hor .selected:before {
  right: 50%;
  margin-right: -2px;
  transform-origin: 100% 0;
  transform: skewX(-45deg);
}
.hor .selected:after {
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -2px;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform: skewX(45deg);
}
ul.ver {
  width: 200px;
}
ul.ver li {
  display: block;
}
ul.ver li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}
.ver .selected:before, .ver .selected:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  height: 9999px;
  width: 7px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 4px 3px 4px 0;
  border-color: blue;
}
.ver .selected:before {
  bottom: 50%;
  margin-bottom: -2px;
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
  transform: skewY(-45deg);
}
.ver .selected:after {
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -2px;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform: skewY(45deg);
}
body {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 20px auto;
  background: rgb(229, 180, 230);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(30deg, rgb(229, 180, 230) 30%, rgb(90, 140, 250) 70%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(30deg, rgb(229, 180, 230) 30%, rgb(90, 140, 250) 70%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(30deg, rgb(229, 180, 230) 30%, rgb(90, 140, 250) 70%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(30deg, rgb(229, 180, 230) 30%, rgb(90, 140, 250) 70%);
  background: linear-gradient(120deg, rgb(229, 180, 230) 30%, rgb(90, 140, 250) 70%);
}
```

```html
<ul class="hor">
  <li><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Ipsum</a></li>
  <li class="selected"><a href="#">Sit amet</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Consectetur</a></li>
</ul>
<br>
<ul class="ver">
  <li><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Ipsum</a></li>
  <li class="selected"><a href="#">Sit amet</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Consectetur</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, so far it's working good on my actual layout, even working when I align the LIs to left, right, or center.

Answer (score 2):

Update: Found using 50.6% on the width calc for the `a` element borders greatly reduces the sub-pixel issues at certain window widths. Snippet updated and here's the fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/5wLe4r3h/

Disclaimer: I don't consider this to be elegant.

I moved the main border to the `li` elements. I'm clearing out the `li.selected` border, and adding before/after partial borders to the `a` elements.

```css
ul.hor li {
    border-bottom:3px solid blue;
    float: left;
}
ul.hor li.selected {
    border-bottom: none;
}
ul.hor li.selected a:before {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -3px;
    left: 0px;
    border-bottom:3px solid blue;
    width: calc(50.6% - 9px);
}
ul.hor li.selected a:after {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -3px;
    right: 0px;
    border-bottom:3px solid blue;
    width: calc(50.6% - 9px);
}
ul li {
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative
}
ul li a {
    display:block;
    padding:10px 15px;
}
ul li.selected a {
    color:green
}
ul li.selected:after {
    content:"";
    width:12px;
    height:12px;
    position:absolute;
    border-top:3px solid blue;
    border-right:3px solid blue;
}
ul.hor li.selected:after {
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:-8px;
    margin:0 auto;
    -moz-transform:rotate(315deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(315deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(315deg);
}
ul.ver li.selected:after {
    right:-5px;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-6px;
    -moz-transform:rotate(225deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(225deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(225deg);
}
ul.ver {
    width:200px;
}
ul.ver li {
    display:block;
    border-right:3px solid blue;
}
ul.ver li a {
    display:block;
    padding:10px 15px;
}
ul.ver li.selected {
    border-right: none;
}
ul.ver li.selected a:before {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    border-right:3px solid blue;
    height: calc(50% - 7px);
}
ul.ver li.selected a:after {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0px;
    border-right:3px solid blue;
    height: calc(50% - 10px);
}
body {
    width:90%;
    margin:20px auto;
    background: rgb(229, 180, 230);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(30deg, rgb(229, 180, 230) 30%, rgb(90, 140, 250) 70%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(30deg, rgb(229, 180, 230) 30%, rgb(90, 140, 250) 70%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(30deg, rgb(229, 180, 230) 30%, rgb(90, 140, 250) 70%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(30deg, rgb(229, 180, 230) 30%, rgb(90, 140, 250) 70%);
    background: linear-gradient(120deg, rgb(229, 180, 230) 30%, rgb(90, 140, 250) 70%);
}
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<ul class="hor">
    <li><a href="#">Lorem</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Ipsum</a>
    </li>
    <li class="selected"><a href="#">Sit amet</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Consectetur</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="clear"></div>
<br>
<ul class="ver">
    <li><a href="#">Lorem</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Ipsum</a>
    </li>
    <li class="selected"><a href="#">Sit amet</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Consectetur</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: But the UL bottom border is not showing on your solution. thanks

Comment: What do you mean, exactly?

Comment: this can be easily done but the problem is I need a bottom border for full width layout. Pls refer to the other solutions, they got it right :)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at what I did for the horizontal list.

```
ul.hor {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

ul.hor li.selected a:after, 
ul.hor li.selected a:before {
    content: "";
    width: 1000%;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 59px;
    bottom: -3px;
    border-bottom:3px solid blue;
    z-index: -1;
}
ul.hor li.selected a:after {
    left: auto;
    right: 58px;
}
```

Basically, don't add border for the ul, instead, add fake border to active element which is Really big. Hide overflow of the ul and voila!

'http://jsfiddle.net/wvs9o8oy/12/'

Comment: I think this is promising, but having trouble fixing the vertical one. Can you help me with it? thanks

Comment: Hey, I've adjusted the vertical one as well, check out the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wvs9o8oy/17/

Answer (score 0):

I made [this](http://jsfiddle.net/wvs9o8oy/16/):

```css
ul li.selected a {
    color:green
}

ul.hor {
    border-bottom:3px solid blue
}

ul.ver {
    width:200px;
    border-right:3px solid blue;
}

ul li {
    display:inline-block;position:relative
}
ul li a {
    display:block;padding:10px 15px;
}

}

ul.ver {
    width:200px;border-right:3px solid blue
}
ul.ver li {
    display:block;
}
ver li a {
    display:block;padding:10px 15px;
}


body {
    width:90%;margin:20px auto;
    background: rgb(229, 180, 230);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(30deg, rgb(229, 180, 230) 30%, rgb(90, 140, 250) 70%);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(30deg, rgb(229, 180, 230) 30%, rgb(90, 140, 250) 70%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(30deg, rgb(229, 180, 230) 30%, rgb(90, 140, 250) 70%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(30deg, rgb(229, 180, 230) 30%, rgb(90, 140, 250) 70%);
background: linear-gradient(120deg, rgb(229, 180, 230) 30%, rgb(90, 140, 250) 70%);

}

.ver {
 position: relative;
}
.ver:after, .arrow_box:before {
    left: 177px;
    top: 95px;
 border: solid;
 content: " ";
 height: 0;
 width: 0;
 position: absolute;
 pointer-events: none;
}

.ver:after {
 border-color: rgba(136, 183, 213, 0);
 border-right-color: blue;
 border-width: 12px;
 margin-top: -12px;
}

.hor {
 position: fixed;
}

.hor:after, .hor:before {
 top: 20px;
 left: 194px;
 border: solid transparent;
 content: " ";
 height: 0;
 max-width: 0;
 position: absolute;
 pointer-events: none;
}

.hor:before {
 border-color: rgba(194, 225, 245, 0);
 border-bottom-color: blue;
 border-width: 10px;
 margin-left: -10px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="hor">
  <div class="arrow_box-vertical">
    <li><a href="#">Lorem</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Ipsum</a>
    </li>
    <li class="selected"><a href="#">Sit amet</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Consectetur</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<ul class="ver">
  <li><a href="#">Lorem</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Ipsum</a>
  </li>
  <li class="selected"><a href="#">Sit amet</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Consectetur</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

It looks horrible in the snippet, please look at the JSFiddle.